# Notepad++ Regular Help list

Tags: notepad++, notepad

Hi i have my list like this :

```
Name | Surname | email |
Name | Surname | email |
Name | Surname | email |
Name | Surname | email |
```

I want to copy all email like this :

```
email
email
email
email
```

How can i do that using regex in notepad++ ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup file and then try this on the backup:

```
Find What: ^(.+) \| (.+) \| (.+) \|
Replace with: \3
```

The parens "()" are capture groups, the "\|"  escapes the pipe symbol so it is not interpreted as a command, the "^" means start of line.

The "\3" means replace what is found with the 3rd capture group.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+\|\h+([^\|\r\n]+)\h+\|`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
  .+                # 1 or more any character but newline
  \|                # a pipe
  \h+               # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  ([^\|\r\n]+)      # group 1, 1 or more any character that is not a pipe or linebreak
  \h+               # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  \|                # a pipe
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1 (i.e. email)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]